# Generate ordered insert statement from a Master-Detail joined query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which yields results from 2 joined tables : 
`Bands` & `Members`

For simplification: [this is the output of the joined query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=37a392e61e4e0b559741db5963daf746) :

[image]

`BandId & memberId` are identity columns

I want to create an `insert` statement query which will add those records but it has to have an order + Identity :

```
insert into bands(band,decade) values('beatles',60)
declare @newBandId int = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into  Members (member, age , relatedBandId)
values('john', 40,@newBandId ),
values('paul', 42,@newBandId ),
values('george', 43,@newBandId ),
values('ringo', 40,@newBandId )


insert into bands(band,decade) values('doors',70)
declare @newBandId int = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- `decalre` again ? error?

insert into  Members (member, age , relatedBandId)
values('jim', 50,@newBandId ),
values('john', 60,@newBandId ),
values('ray', 40,@newBandId ),
values('robbie', 20,@newBandId )
```

Band and Members are tables on server 1. I need to generate the data on server 2. ( which also have Bands and Members tables , but with different data).
So I want to create an insert statement query.

I can't run cross db's query due to orgaization security restrictions, nor import.

So I must create an insert statement query - which will yield long insert statement query.
I don't have a problem concatenating strings along the rows, it's just that I need to run insert for a band (one time only), and then get the identity, and only then run 3 inserts for members.

**Question:**

How can I create an insert statement from this joined query via phases described above ?

[**Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=37a392e61e4e0b559741db5963daf746)

Comment: So, what result set are you after here exactly? What do you mean by an "order + identity"? You say that you can't run cross database queries, however what does that have to do with the data here? Both `band` and `Members` are in the same database (and schema) in your sample DDL.

Comment: @Larnu in server1 I have bands and members. After a while , (week or so) , I need to synchronize changes to server2 ( which also have bands and members) . I don;t care about identities to be the same. At the end I have a query of master-details , which I want to generate an insert script which I can run on server2.problem is that the final script should contain details insertions for master insetion.

Comment: You don't mention linked servers at all in your question here. We're missing some key information here. Your sample data, to get the right results, is based on knowledge of the Beatles and the Doors; something SQL Server has no knowledge of. Show us what your actual data looks like, and explain the end goal. If there are (un)linked servers involved, then why are you omitting that information when it appears to be key to the question?

Comment: @Larnu I've mentioned it explictly: _I can't run cross db's query due to orgaization security restrictions, nor import._

Comment: Are you, at a guess, asking how you can take the data from the above dataset, and turn it into an `INSERT` statement for 2 tables (`band` and `Members`)?

Comment: Do you mean cross server queries?

Comment: @Larnu I can't (no matter which approach) access in the same query  , to different servers. there is no problem generating insert statement for a band. the problem is to generate for each inserted band , its members. in a single query

Comment: So, if you're not having a problem creating an `INSERT` statement, what are you having problems with? You still haven't explained.

Comment: @Larnu bandID is identity ( I will clarify it) . I don't know `relatedBandId`. I should create a script that insert band , get identity , and then for that identity , insert members. And then again for the second band....

Comment: Which leads me back to my qusetion earlier "Are you asking how you can take the data from the above dataset, and turn it into an INSERT statement for 2 tables (`band` and `Members`)?" If the answer is "Yes", then I believe I know what you're after. if the answer is "No", then explain your needs.

Comment: @Larnu yes, but with order. ( first band and then members)

Comment: OK, *now* we're getting somewhere. :)

Comment: @Larnu Ok. thanks ( and sorry) if I wasn't clear.

Comment: And you want to create an new ID for these bands in the new table, not retain the old one?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, they will have new id's. The table on both servers are very different (identity POV). Beatles is 1 on server 1  , but can be 700 in server 2. It's only important that beatles members on server2 , will have 700 in relatedBandId

Comment: OK, then that poses a problem. I can think of a way, but you'll have to add (and then remove) a column to your table `band` in the process, is that ok? If not how do you propose you get the value of the new ID, without retention of the Old ID (I don't suggest basing it on Names, as they can be non-unique)

Comment: @Larnu after each and insertion , I read scope_identity....no ? I've mentioned it in question... :) that will be relatedBandId.

Comment: That's going to make for a very slow `INSERT`, as you'd have to use a `WHILE`; that's hardly ideal.

Comment: @Larnu the sync query will run at night. performance is not an issue here